# Basic List of tuple iteration

Tags: python, iterator, tuples, list-comprehension, python-itertools

hi all im stuck at my python script i have 2list a&b 
The list A contain tuple which iuse for looping trought the list 
The b contain only value that i want to increment  so each time the "a" complete i want to return  value

```
A=[(a,b,c),(a,b,c).(a,b,c),(a,b,c)]
B=["a","b","c",'d']
for x in a:
  Print " yo"
  itert=B.__iter()__
  Y=itert.next()
  print y
```

and its returning `yo a,yo a,yo a,yo a  yo b,yo b,yo b,yo b,yo b ...`

But i want `yo a,yo b,yo c,yo d, yo a,yo b,yo c,yo d ...`

Sorry for the exeple but its the best way i can explain thx a lot

Comment: Would you please either work to make the question more clear, or give us code that actually does what you're describing? Currently, I can't understand either the question or the non-working code.

Comment: This code isn't valid Python. Why don't you post the actual code you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea im sorry ,im really not good in english  what I meant is Iterating two list a the same time like

for a,b in zip(listA,listB):
    print a,b

Its basic list iteration im really sorry for my bad 
English and exemple

Answer (score 2):

As bizarre and broken as your code is, each time through the loop you are resetting `itert` to `B.__iter__()`. This goes back to the beginning of list `B`, so `Y` is always set to `"a"`.

The actual output of the (corrected) code is:

```
 yo
a
 yo
a
 yo
a
 yo
a
```

I guess that you need something like this nested loop?

```
a=b=c=1   # so definition of A succeeds
A=[(a,b,c),(a,b,c),(a,b,c),(a,b,c)]
B=['a','b','c','d']
for x in A:
    for y in B:
        print "yo %s," % y,
print
```